# How to stop Push Notification from automatically opening app?

Tags: android, push-notification

I have an Android App with Push Notifications. I'm having a problem with some devices that when I send a push notification, the user's app opens automatically. I don't want to do that. I want the notification to show normally and if the users clicks on it, the app opens.

How do I prevent the app from opening automatically?

Here is the code from my intent for push notifications:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

notificationIntent.setFlags(
        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, requestID, notificationIntent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

// Display a notification with an icon, message as content, and default sound. It also
// opens the app when the notification is clicked.
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setContentTitle(title)
        .setContentText(message)
        .setColor(0xFF221E80)
        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setFullScreenIntent(contentIntent, true)
        .setContentIntent(contentIntent);

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(
        Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you take a look at the documentation for the `NotificationCompat.Builder` you can see the `setFullScreenIntent` is the issue.

[Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setFullScreenIntent(android.app.PendingIntent,%20boolean)) on that call:

> An intent to launch instead of posting the notification to the status bar. Only for use with extremely high-priority notifications demanding the user's immediate attention, such as an incoming phone call or alarm clock that the user has explicitly set to a particular time. If this facility is used for something else, please give the user an option to turn it off and use a normal notification, as this can be extremely disruptive.
>
> On some platforms, the system UI may choose to display a heads-up notification, instead of launching this intent, while the user is using the device.

You should remove `setFullScreenIntent` from your builder.